# TF2 – Engine out of memory

Tags: technical-issues, team-fortress-2, macos

Whenever I join a multiplayer game in Team Fortress 2, I can play for about a minute, and after that I get an error message and the game crashes.

The error message is: `Engine Error: Out of memory`

Screenshot:

[image: Error message display]

This shouldn't be happening – I have a good 8GB of RAM.

I've turned a few advanced video settings to `LOW`, including:

- `Shader detail`
- `Color correction` is `DISABLED`
- `Water detail` is `Simple reflections`

Any fixes?

**Reference:**

- 27" iMac
- Running OS X 10.11 El Capitan
- 8GB RAM
- Intel Core i5, 3.2 GHz Quad-core

Comment: That looks like a Mac error.  If not, what OS are you using?

Comment: @Frank Mac OS X. Forgot to include that, sorry.

Comment: What happens if you turn _all_ the graphics settings to low? I'm seeing a lot of other Mac users on the Steam forums encountering the same issue.

Comment: Are you on the most recent version of OS X? Check for updates and install any, that tends to fix the problem

Comment: @pushasha Your fix seems to work..however, I may need to do a bit more testing before I can confirm that it is solid. I'll most likely have a cogent answer to your fix by tonight.

Comment: @will309 Yeah, I'm on OS X 10.11.5 – the most recent version available.

Comment: @pushasha Yep, your fix seems to check out.

Comment: @Angelplayer Just posted it as an answer. Glad it worked! I wish there was a better solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's not exactly a "fix" (since 8GB of RAM should be plenty to play TF2, as you mentioned), try turning *all* the graphics settings down to "Low" or "Disabled". A lot of other Mac users are [running into out-of-memory issues when playing TF2 recently](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3301320), and it seems that turning down all the graphics settings to the lowest values has helped a significant number of them.